# Problem enabling local targets in Jitterbit

Tags: sync

I use Jitterbit 7.1 and when I want to sync data from Salesforce into local file I got error saying:

"Using local files as source/target is disabled by default. Set EnableLocalFileLocation=true in the [Settings] section of 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Jitterbit Agent\jitterbit.conf' and restart the Jitterbit Apache service to enable it."

Jitterbit documentation says that to do this you need to go to Administration console (View > Administration). But I don`t have Administration in my view tab or in any other tabs so I can`t open Administration console. Are there any other ways to open that console or enable local targets?

Answer (score -2):

I have this exact issue on **Jitterbit Studio 8.1**  (30 day trial). Agreed, the documentation is incorrect; there is **NO ADMINISTRATION menu item** under the View menu.

Please note:
Setting "EnableLocalFileLocation=true", AND removing the preceding hash (comment mark), in C:\Program Files (x86)\Jitterbit Agent\jitterbit.conf, plus restarting any/all agent services, in many instances will not be enough to allow the use of locally stored target or source files.

I recommend you use "Temporary Files" which do work and are saved to the JB cloud servers.

Comment: @RafaelSuarez Chris was indeed right, if you're new to how this site works I'd recommend you have a look at our [welcome tour](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour). This will show you that answers really are only intended to post solutions to the question asked. This doesn't work like another forum where answers can be seen as replies in a conversation. Some parts of your answer do provide relevant additional info, I would suggest you try to edit your answer to put focus on that, and that alone.

Comment: OK, then my apologies to you both Chris and Samuel. Answer improved.